# How can I enable a virtual machine on KVM to use the WiFi connection on my Ubuntu 18 laptop?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, thinkpad, virt-manager

I recently set up KVM hypervisor on my Ubuntu 18 LTS ThinkPad Carbon. I installed qemu, virt-manager, and libvirt to manage the VMs.

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils virt-manager
```

I have also added my user to the appropriate groups.

```
sudo adduser [username] libvirt
sudo adduser [username] libvirt-qemu
```

...and enabled virtualization in the BIOS.

However, none of the VMs I boot up have an internet connection. I assume that is because KVM is designed to be hosted on a server on a wired network, and I am trying to launch the VMs locally with only a WiFi connection.

How can I enable VMs on my laptop to have an internet connection? Do I need to install a certain driver, set up a subnetwork on Virtualization Manager, or set up a 'bridge' between the host and guest machines?

Comment: Your Assumption is wrong, the hypervisor doesn't care how it's connected upstream. You can set up a NATed Network in Virt-Manager using the GUI. You can also bridge with WIFI, if your Wifi-card (and AP) can do "4addr mode" (WDS). This is what i usually do for VMs on my notebook. Google, or ask more specific questions.

Comment: I updated this question in  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111768/how-do-i-configure-dhcp-bridge-with-netplan-for-kvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1111993#1111993

Comment: @JustinBrunkow Please don't double post the same question. BTW Your AskUbuntu question got an upvote while this got a downvote. This question isn't really a question, the other was.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the default **yaml** file in **/etc/netplan** as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp0s25
```